# I try to create a custom querybuilder with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I have a OneToMany relationship on these 2 entities:

- `Article`
- `ArticleLikes`

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ArticleRepository::class)
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $relation;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ArticleLikes::class, mappedBy="article")
     */
    private $articleLikes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->articleLikes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRelation(): ?User
    {
        return $this->relation;
    }

    public function setRelation(?User $relation): self
    {
        $this->relation = $relation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ArticleLikes[]
     */
    public function getArticleLikes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->articleLikes;
    }

    public function addArticleLike(ArticleLikes $articleLike): self
    {
        if (!$this->articleLikes->contains($articleLike)) {
            $this->articleLikes[] = $articleLike;
            $articleLike->setArticle($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeArticleLike(ArticleLikes $articleLike): self
    {
        if ($this->articleLikes->removeElement($articleLike)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($articleLike->getArticle() === $this) {
                $articleLike->setArticle(null);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isLikedByUser(User $user): bool
    {
        foreach ($this->getArticleLikes() as $like)
        {
            if ($like->getUser() === $user) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ArticleLikesRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ArticleLikesRepository::class)
 */
class ArticleLikes
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Article::class, inversedBy="articleLikes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $article;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="articleLikes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getArticle(): ?Article
    {
        return $this->article;
    }

    public function setArticle(?Article $article): self
    {
        $this->article = $article;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The `Article` entity can contain a collection of `ArticleLikes`.

In the `ArticleLikes` entity, each like is related to an `Article` (`articleId`) as well as to a user field (`userId`).

To retrieve the number of likes for each article, I have a method in the `Article` entity:

```
/ **
 * @return Collection | ArticleLikes []
 * /
public function getArticleLikes (): Collection
{
    return $ this-> articleLikes;
}
```

I am lost because I would like to create a query that allows **you to retrieve the last 10 articles the most liked** (with the most of `ArticleLikes`). I don't know if I need to do a left join or something else. How can I do this query?

I want to retrieve the 10 articles that have the most `ArticleLikes`.

Image:
[image: 1]

Comment: One of your edits seems to contain a solution. Please post that as an answer so others can maybe benefit from it and show that you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put:

```
->orderBy('count(al)', 'DESC')
```

Query Builder that gets the 10 most liked articles:

```
/**
 * @return array
 *  get the 10 most liked articles
 */
public function findArticlesMostLiked(): array
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select( 'a')
        ->join('a.articleLikes', 'al')
        ->groupBy('al.article')
        ->orderBy('count(al)', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(10)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
}
```